# When multiple Jedi attack one target, why do they all attack physically?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Jedi are masters of telepathy, telekinesis, and physical combat.

When two or more Jedi attack one target, why do they all crowd around to physically confront him?

The gang should have some Jedi mentally attacking their target, some Jedi using physical force attacks (whether on the target or by smashing things into his legs/face), and some using physical combat.

One example is Qui-gon versus Darth Maul, while Obi Wan had to watch through the laser gate. The Force can cross star systems, so Obi Wan could have done telekinetic nut punches to Maul.  Or, even better for their mission, scanned Maul's brain to learn his secrets while Maul was concentrating on his fight with Qui-gon.

Comment: Because they're dumb.

Comment: @Richard - you should always [attribute your quotes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7XVcqZodAM) :)

Comment: @DVK - I didn't even remember that. LOL :-)

Comment: Possible dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19211/why-didnt-the-fighters-use-force-pull-push-in-the-generator-complex

Comment: @Richard - I'm on the fence on that being a duplicate... good find!

Comment: @DVK - I'm sure there was a question about why the jedi don't use their powers more often, in general. I just can't find it.

Comment: @Richard - I remember that one. I think I may have answered it actually

Comment: There's like half a dozen related questions (look for "force battle", "force powers") but none that really meet the measure for a dupe IMO.

Comment: See, when my Sith apprentice and I attack a Jedi, it goes like this: 1) I choke the Jedi while lifting them several feet into the air, then 2) she throws her lightsaber into the air, neatly slicing the distracted Jedi in half. Then the Jedi's Padawan usually screams, which is always fun.

Comment: @Omegacron It seems like you're missing out on a lot of fun, though. Do you save the "telekinetic nut punches" for the Padawan, or what?

Comment: `The Force can cross star systems, so Obi Wan could have done telekinetic nut punches to Maul.` ~> Haha. Seriously?

Comment: @Richard - this would be the exception that proves the rule.

Answer (score 5):

Although I do not know if there is a direct answer to this question, I do have some ideas that might explain the general use of force powers in battle.

Very simply put, I believe the use of Force abilities to offensively attack an opponent **brings the user closer to the dark side**, and **goes against the Jedi's ultimate goal of disarming or incapacitating the opponent**.

At a very high level, force moves are generally **very aggressive when directed at another being** (force push/pull or telekinesis are popular in the movies.)  The Sith actually use the force in nearly every fight in the movies (Ex. Force Lightning by Sidious, Force Choke by Vader, Force Push by Anakin/Dooku/Sidious).  The Jedi actually use non-combative force powers in combat that may not get qualified as 'Force moves' in the movies, but utilize The Force the same and draw the same amount of focus by the user (Ex: Healing/Meditation/Speed etc.)  First let's look at the movie examples (just prequels are enough to prove the point):

Qui-Gon/Obi-wan vs. Darth Maul - Force Leap and Force Telekinesis, and Qui-Gon uses Force Meditation during the fight.

Yoda/Anakin/Obi-Wan vs. Count Dooku - Anakin uses a Force Leap/Dash, Yoda makes use of Force Telekinesis.

Anakin/Obi-Wan vs. Count Dooku - Force Leaps to dodge

Anakin/Obi-Wan vs. Grievous - Force Telekinesis/Force Leaps

Obi-Wan vs. Grievous - Force Telekinesis/Force Leap

Mace Windu vs. Sidious/Anakin - Note that Mace's lightsaber form [Vaapad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII) is an adaptation of Juyo.  See below for more on forms.

Yoda vs. Sidious - Most force moves used by a Jedi here.  Force Deflection, Force Leap, Force Telekinesis.

Obi-Wan vs Vader - Force Leaps/Force Telekinesis.  This is the most aggressive we see Obi-Wan with the force in the movies, possibly representing his emotional investment in Anakin as we see at the end of the battle (breaking the Jedi code of course).

The pattern here is that most of the Jedi Force uses are **defensive** in nature and used at times to either counter another opponent move or draw an object away or towards the Jedi.

Additionally, if you look at the saber forms of the Jedi, [Juyo/Vaapad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII) is the most aggressive of the saber form and requires a furious offense of attacks utilizing a **large stream of force in addition to force attacks**.  This form was favored by many Sith and is the form that would gain the most from aggressive Force abilities in combat.  Vaapad was similar and **banned by the Jedi** for its Force requirement leans in the direction of the dark side.

Lastly, I believe this there is some reference to this topic in the EU in the Heir to the Empire series.

Comment: Telekinetic nut punches should disarm or incapacitate Maul... and would have been way better comic relief than Jar Jar

Comment: And an attempt to read Maul's mind would not be a vicious attack.  Windu's orders, in fact, were "Go with the Queen to Naboo and discover the identity of the dark warrior. That is the clue we need to unravel this mystery of the Sith."

Comment: @DanJameson I'm not so sure reading the mind of Darth Maul is even possible.  Remember the dark side clouds all things.  Darth Maul's mind was likely filled with rage at the time.  Also, he is a veteran and likely knows techniques to protect his mind from being read.

Comment: A decent answer, but it fails to account for the fact that Force moves take concentration & focus, something which isn't always possible in combat. I say add that as a second possible reason, and you have a pretty solid answer.

Comment: @Omegacron I agree 100%, but the problem is that it takes the same amount of focus for the Jedi and the Sith.  So that wouldn't explain why **the Jedi** use force moves less frequently in combat then the Sith, which was part of the original question

Comment: When Obi Wan was separate from the battle by the laser gate, he had all the concentration and focus he needed, while Darth Maul was busy fighting.  I totally buy that you can't to TK or psi attacks in combat because the other guy is right there to attack you, but when you are sitting back and not fighting you have that opening.

Comment: @DanJameson If you are asking specifically about that fight, you must also remember that Obi-Wan was not a Jedi Knight at the time and very young.  **There is no evidence that suggests that Obi-Wan could read his mind even if he tried**.  Darth Maul was a Sith Lord as mentioned in the movie.  I am not sure how you can assume a Jedi Padawan can so easily read the mind of a Sith Lord.

Comment: FYI - in the Darth Maul graphic novel when he is taking down Black Sun, one of the Vigo bodyguards, a telepathic Iktochi - tries to read Maul's mind to determine who he works for. It is extremely difficult, and once Maul voluntarily lets him in, the guy basically goes catatonic after saying "So... dark...". Fun bit of trivia.

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - But hypothetically speaking, let's say several relatively powerful Jedi are facing a single opponent (e.g., Yoda, Obi Wan, Windu, Koon, and Fisto vs. Darth Maul).  Maybe one of the Jedi engage Maul in a duel just to keep him occupied, and maintains a purely defensive stance.  Couldn't the other four combine their energies to use Force techniques and render Maul powerless, or incapacitate him?  Since the alternative is to hack him apart with laser beams until he dies, surely using Force powers to capture him is the less aggressive option.

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - and if four Jedi aren't enough, make it every Jedi ever - the implausibility of getting them all in one room with Maul notwithstanding, it seems certain that by using nonviolent Force techniques, they could subdue him peacefully and no one would need to draw their weapon or risk injury/death to do it.

Comment: @WadCheber I would argue that using that solution is even worse!  "Absolute power corrupts absolutely."  By inflicting the force powers as you describe is inherently evil.  What's to stop all Jedi from doing this always?  And you use this technique once and you realize how powerful you are.  What is there to stop you from doing it again?  And the others from doing it to you?  And what about non-force users?  You can crush them!  This is definitely down the dark path...

Comment: @MatthewFrontino The Jedi have the power to dismember Force-user and non-Force-users alike with laserswords.  That seems like a more dangerous amount of power than what amounts to a Force-tazer, used to disarm and arrest people who are armed and intend to kill you and enslave trillions of people.  The Jedi are allowed to arrest people, but in most cases, they just kill them on the spot.  Disarming and apprehending their opponents would be more merciful, less aggressive, and would be less of an abuse/use of "force" (as opposed to "[the] Force").

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - Are cops using/abusing their power more when they mace/taze an armed criminal who clearly means to hurt/kill others, or when they just shoot him in the face?

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - The Force power I'm thinking of don't include lightning, choking, push/pulling him to his death, or "inflicting" pain/discomfort/injury of any kind - more like freezing him in his tracks, taking his lightsaber away, cuffing him, and putting him in a humane, reasonably  comfortable holding cell.  Compared to Mace Windu wanting to summarily decapitate Palpatine, or Obi Wan tearing open Grievous' sternum and shooting him directly in the heart, or lopping off his best friend's arm and legs and leaving him to burn alive, it seems like an improvement and reduction of force.

Comment: @WadCheber It's more like the police being able to subdue you by pressing a button to activate a chip in your brain.  And yes I absolutely have an issue with that.  Note that Mace uses a saber form that is considered incredibly dangerous and not-jedi-approved, so he's not exactly the paragon of light side techniques.  It's imposing your will upon another who cannot defend themselves from these mental attacks, and that is just not something that Jedi do.  In SWTOR, that's the type of thing that would earn you dark side points

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - but if "the Jedi could use this on non-Force-users" is a legitimate objection, they shouldn't be allowed to use lightsabers either, and since lightsabers kill you, but the Force techniques I'm talking about don't even cause pain, the lightsabers are FAR more problematic.  If the Jedi sent the people they arrested to court, and it was discovered that the Jedi had misused their power, the defendant would be released without charge and the Jedi would be disciplined.  And since a non-Force-user stands a better chance of resisting Force power than a lightsaber, he's better off.

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - let's take this debate to the question I just asked: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89320/could-several-jedi-peacefully-overpower-one-sith-opponent-through-nonviolent-for?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with honor. Note in episode 3 Anakin was very conflicted on executing Dooku, and didn't kill the unarmed sith until after being prodded by Palpatine and giving into his own hatred. As the most powerful men and women in the universe having order and justice was most important. Their lightsabers show that a peaceful resistance is more helpful than oppression; they deflect bullets and other attacks because using it as a weapon.

I don't know much about non-movie canon, but a sense of honor has always been present in the jedi order in the movies. Its arguable that by attacking Maul physically and psychically would be poor sportsmanship because he would have too many things to focus on.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that I put down my sword and you put down your rock, and we try to kill each other like civilized people?

Comment: @KSmarts I just want you to feel you’re doing well. I hate for people to die embarrassed.